# TextInputLayout not reverting original edit text background on setError(null)

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-textinputlayout

I am using **TextInputLayout** with **AppCompatEditText** having a custom xml shape based background for **AppCompatEditText**.

My **TextInputLayout** is:

[image]

Where **@drawable/edittext_bg** is :

[image]

When i set some error on **TextInputLayout**, the background turns red which is OK. But on removing error using **setError(null)**, the background turns grey, not the original one.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Comment: hello you got the solution ??

Comment: got the solution of the above problem if you set the background image to EditText then this problem occur

Comment: No solution found yet,,,had to use hard backgrounds instead of xml drawables. :(